# Compare values from two different dictionaries in Python?

Tags: python

I have searched the previous posts and have not found one where the person asking is doing quite what I'm trying to do:

I am trying to look through two separate dictionaries and find instances where the keys are the same, but the values are different.  The dictionaries are *not* the same size.  When I find matching keys that have different values, I want to add just the keys to a list as I will not need the values anymore.

Right now I am doing this.  It is horribly inefficient, but is ok for 200-ish items.  I have some dictionaries that are over 200,000 items, though, and that is where this becomes a major problem:

```
    for sourceKey, sourceValue in sourceDict.iteritems():
         for targetKey, targetValue in targetDict.iteritems():
              if targetKey == sourceKey:
                   if targetValue != sourceValue:
                        diffList.append(sourceKey)
```

Is there a way to do this at all?  I am using Python 2.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for key in set(sourceDict).intersection(targetDict):
    # Now we have only keys that occur in both dicts
    if sourceDict[key] != targetDict[key]:
        diffList.append(key)
```

As DSM noted in his (now deleted) answer, you can do this with a list comprehension or generator:

```
(k for k in set(sourceDict).intersection(targetDict) if sourceDict[key] != targetDict[key])
```

Comment: Hmmph.  Seven seconds you beat me by!  I don't think you need to call `.keys()`, though-- that will create an unnecessary intermediate list.

Comment: @DSM noted. I'm actually a little surprised there isn't a duck-typing mechanism for treating a dict's keys like a set, since they're next-of-kin anyway.

Comment: Actually, these days calling `.keys()` gives you a `dict_keys()` object, and `a.keys() & b` does what you'd think it does!  [We're working with 2.6 here, though, so no fun.]

Comment: Fantastic!  I didn't expect an answer in such a short period of time.  Thank you both very much!  As for the answer provided by DSM, as well as Ranjan, how would I get what is returned into the diffList?  Does that code return another dictionary?

Comment: @user2259908 With parens it's a *generator expression*, which means it returns a generator. A generator lazily yields each value in it when you call `next()` on it. With square brackets it's a *list comprehension*, which means it returns a list. As a list, the values are calculated immediately, and those values are stored in memory. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789/generator-expressions-vs-list-comprehension

Answer (score 0):

```
[k for k in source_dict if target_dict.get(k, object()) != source_dict[k]]
```

Answer (score 0):

1-liner: `[key for key in set(sourceDict).intersection(targetDict) if sourceDict[key] != targetDict[key]]`